# Activity run by asynctask read sharedpreferences incorrectly?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have weird problem which causes me headache for week already.

I use sort of switcher which changes title of item in actionbar and makes sure title is correctly set. For saving state of this item I use sharedpreferences.

In other part of application I use asynctask. Problem is that while asynctask is running, BaseActivity reads wrong value of actionbar setting, so it has incorrect title until asynctask finishes.

I prepared for you example of this bug. Weird thing is, that if I change activity from ExtendActivity to RefreshActivity in method onPostExecute, surprisingly it does read and set correct title. Of course I can't do that in real application.

BaseActivity:

```
    public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean menub;
    public Menu menu;
    public SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         this.pref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        this.menub = pref.getBoolean("menub", true);
        _switch(false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, RefreshActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_test:
                _switch(true);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    public void _switch(boolean swtch) {
        String n;
        if (swtch) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = pref.edit();
            if (menub) {
                e.putBoolean("menub",false);
                n="A";
            }
            else {
                e.putBoolean("menub", true);
                n="B";
            }
            e.apply();
        }
        else {
            if (menub) n="B";
            else n="A";
        }
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_test).setTitle(n);      
    }
}
```

RefreshActivity:

```
public class RefreshActivity extends BaseActivity {

    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    public Activity thisActivity;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        thisActivity=this;  
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b==null) {
            load();
        }
        else {
            if (b.containsKey("loaded")) {
                new _async().execute();
            }
        }
    }
    private class _async extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            return 1;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer response) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity,ExtendActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_folder", 0);
            startActivity(intent); 
            thisActivity.finish();
        }
     }
    public void load() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,RefreshActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("loaded",true);
        startActivity(intent); 
        ((Activity) this).finish();
    }
}
```

ExtendActivity:

```
public class ExtendActivity extends RefreshActivity {

}
```

menu.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_test"
              android:title="A"
              android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is happening, but perhaps `getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` is reading the wrong file by default.  Have you tried `getSharedPreferences()` with a consistent file name?

Comment: Dude, you was right! I incorrectly thought that I read in android docs that getPreferences() uses only one file per app, but now i read that it's per activity. It works with getSharedPreferences() correctly. If you answer my question properly i will mark your response as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help, but "dude" is a little too informal for me, "Sam" is fine.  I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPreferences()` can be tricky, it assumes that you only want your SharedPreferences file to be use by one Activity.  (Glance at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.getPreferences%28int%29) if you want details.)  I suggest using [`getSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a consistent file name instead.  This way ExtendActivity, RefreshActivity, and BaseActivity will all read from the same file.